# how to install Devstack on Ubuntu 16.04 Server

Tags: openstack

As I made for the previously release of DevStack, for install it I've always run the same steps:

**1 - Create a Stack user:**

```
$: sudo groupadd stack
$: sudo useradd -g stack -s /bin/bash -d /opt/stack -m stack
$: sudo passwd stack
$: sudo visudo
```

then add line

```
stack ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

save the file and exit, logout and login as that user.

**2 - Download the pack:**

```
$: git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack -b stable/mitaka
```

**3 - Create a local.conf**

using this guide, https://gist.github.com/amotoki/b5ca4affd768177ed911

```
$: nano local.conf
```

**4 - Install Devstack**

```
$: ./stack
```

but I get an error like this:

```
[ERROR] ./stack.sh:191 If you wish to run this script anyway run with FORCE=yes
/home/richardsith/devstack/functions-common: line 232: /opt/stack/logs/error.log: No such file or directory
```

the line 191 says:

```
# Warn users who aren't on an explicitly supported distro, but allow them to
# override check and attempt installation with ``FORCE=yes ./stack``
if [[ ! ${DISTRO} =~ (trusty|vivid|wily|7.0|wheezy|sid|testing|jessie|f22|f23|rhel7|kvmibm1) ]]; then
    echo "WARNING: this script has not been tested on $DISTRO"
    if [[ "$FORCE" != "yes" ]]; then
        die $LINENO "If you wish to run this script anyway run with FORCE=yes"
    fi
fi
```

this task was passed using the command:

```
$: FORCE=yes ./stack
```

but during the procedure I receive this error:

```
2016-06-07 13:47:08.494 | +lib/keystone:configure_keystone:194       cp -p /opt/stack/keystone/etc/policy.json /etc/keystone
2016-06-07 13:47:08.496 | cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/keystone/policy.json': Permission denied
2016-06-07 13:47:08.503 | +lib/keystone:configure_keystone:1         exit_trap
2016-06-07 13:47:08.509 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:474                  local r=1
2016-06-07 13:47:08.514 | ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:475                  jobs -p
2016-06-07 13:47:08.520 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:475                  jobs=
2016-06-07 13:47:08.525 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:478                  [[ -n '' ]]
2016-06-07 13:47:08.530 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:484                  kill_spinner
2016-06-07 13:47:08.535 | +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:370               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2016-06-07 13:47:08.541 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:486                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
2016-06-07 13:47:08.547 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:487                  echo 'Error on exit'
2016-06-07 13:47:08.547 | Error on exit
2016-06-07 13:47:08.552 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  generate-subunit 1465306861 367 fail
2016-06-07 13:47:08.965 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:489                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
2016-06-07 13:47:08.970 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:492                  /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
2016-06-07 13:47:09.480 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:498                  exit 1
```

also this step has been resolved run the command where the installer was stopped, in this case

```
$: sudo cp -p /opt/stack/keystone/etc/policy.json /etc/keystone
$: FORCE=yes ./stack
```

same step for all the error received during the installation.....

Why if I set the Stack user with sudo privileges receive the error of permission denied? 
thanks in advance

Comment: What's on `stack.sh` line 191?  It looks like you don't have permissions to `/opt/stack/logs`, does your user have sudo permissions?

Comment: If you have no choice, try to use `FORCE=yes ./stack.sh` as root.

Comment: @bc2946088 I followed this link for the permissions http://www.unixarena.com/2015/08/how-to-deploy-openstack-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: @Bilal the right command to force the installation is that "FORCE=yes ./stack.sh" the script now starting but received that as error "cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/keystone/policy.json': Permission denied"

Answer (score 1):

```
Official guide.
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/ 
My guide.
apt-get update
cd /
git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack
optionally -b stable/juno || stable/liberty || stable/mitaka
cd devstack/
cp samples/local.conf local.conf
vi local.conf
ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
MYSQL_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
/devstack/tools/create-stack-user.sh
chown -R stack:stack /devstack
su stack
/devstack/stack.sh
```

**Don't use root/sudo for `./stack` or `./rejoin`. It will break your installation**

Answer (score 0):

Messing up with permissions like that won't get you anywhere.. If you don't want to use the tested 14.04 lts, perhaps you can use docker, and simply follow the official procedure as described [here](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Docker)..

Answer (score 0):

i have this probleme in installl ./stack.sh 
/devstack/functions-common:265 Support for xenial is incomplete: no support for invalid hardware type -

Comment: that's not an answer, more a question; Please ask your own question